# Как изменить, добавить значения в Cookie на C#?

Tags: cookie, c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить или изменить значения в принятых Cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cookie ck = new Cookie("name", "value"); //создаем новую печеньку
CookieCollection ckCol = new CookieCollection(); //создаем коллекцию для хранения
ckCol.Add(ck); //добавляем нашу куку в коллекцию
```

Значения кукисов в коллекции можно перегнать в контейнер кукисов самого запроса:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); //создаем запрос
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(); //инициализируем контейнер
request.CookieContainer.Add(ckCol); //добавляем наши куки
```

Значения полученных кукисов можно взять так:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); //получаем ответ
Cookie ck = response.Cookies[name]; //возвращает Cookie с указанным именем
```

Comment: Скажите а порядок этих пар ключ/значение важен в куках? а то получается что таким способом в конец наверно добавляется все время

Comment: Вы можите сами создать новую CookieCollection, и заполнить его по порядку из ответа таким образом:
CookieCollection ckCol = new CookieCollection();
ckCol.Add(response.Cookies.Items[0]); 

Изменяя индекс, их можно переставить местами.

Comment: Советую вам почитать http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/!

Comment: Спасибо вам большое.
Все дело из за того что я не могу выполнить программно переход по ссылке вида < a href= ... , так бы я и не парился с этими куками вообще, просто выполнил бы GET запрос и принял бы куки.

Comment: Всмысле не можите программно перейти? Что именно не получается?

Comment: Разобрался :)

Comment: Замечательно!